# How to verify signed certificate timestamps (SCTs) in Go

Tags: http, go, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am writing a Go HTTP client application and it needs to verify the SCTs in order to take advantage of Certificate Transparency. Is this automatically supported in the latest Go version? How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects here:

1. retrieving SCTs from the TLS connection
2. verifying the SCTs against CT logs

**Retrieving SCTs** is easily done in the standard library, with three different cases per [RFC 6962](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962.html#page-13):

- as an extension in the leaf certificate itself
- as a TLS extension in the handshake
- in the OCSP response

All of them are available through the [tls.ConnectionState](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#ConnectionState) in their respective fields:

- `state.PeerCertificates[0].Extensions`, under the extension with ID `asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 11129, 2, 4, 2}`
- `state.SignedCertificateTimestamps`
- `state.OCSPResponse`

Those still need to be parsed properly.

**Verifying SCTs** is trickier and is **not** part of the standard library. This involves the following:

- having a list of trusted CT logs
- finding the CT log whose public key was used to sign the SCT
- verifying the signature
- verifying inclusion of the certificate in the CT's merkle tree and checking timestamps

This can be cobbled together using the [certificate-transparency-go](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency-go) utilities, but they have not included a quick and easy way to use it as a library.

One library that attempts to make all of this easier is available at [github.com/mberhault/go-sct](https://github.com/mberhault/go-sct). It can be used as follows to verify the SCTs after a HTTPS GET:

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of `github.com/mberhault/go-sct`.

```golang
import "github.com/mberhault/go-sct"

// Verifying the SCTs after a HTTPS GET request.
resp, err := http.Get("https://www.certificate-transparency.org")
if err != nil {
    panic("get failed " + err.Error())
}

err = sct.CheckConnectionState(resp.TLS)
if err != nil {
    panic("SCT check failed " + err.Error())
}
```

The same can be done on the tls.ConnectionState obtained through other methods (on a `tls.Conn`, or in the `tls.Config.VerifyConnection` callback).

Comment: I have run into this library a couple of times but don't exactly understand how it is meant to be used. I will look deeper.

Comment: It's used to build CT servers and monitors, not for client-side checking. Although it does include all the functionality to do it, it's just not so trivial.

Comment: Any good reason why this isn't just baked in the http client? I can't even find anyone asking for this functionality. Are people still using certificate pinning or is this just something nobody is really worried about?

Comment: Verifying SCTs is not a cheap proposition, it potentially adds quite a few extras round trips. But that just means it should be optional. I'm as baffled as you are about why it's not included, CT has been around for quite a few years.

Comment: There's a [prototype library](https://github.com/mberhault/go-sct) available, but read the caveats.

Comment: That project definitely helps give some guidance. It would be great if you can edit the original response or add a new one with that prototype link to make it more visible to anyone looking for an example of how this could be accomplished. Thanks for all your answers this has been very educational.

Comment: I've clarified the answer and provided a code sample.